# Brief moment about Beta function from Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Am I right that here before using Holder's inequality we must prove that beta-function always converges for $x>0,y>0$. Right?

Comment: What was Theorem $8.18$ ?

Comment: It was about that $\log \Gamma$ is convex.

Answer (score 1):

Holder works even if the starting integral equals $\infty.$ But it's good see the integral converges here to hone your skills. All you need to verify is that the integrand is on the order of $t^{x-1}$ near $0$ and on the order of $(1-t)^{y-1}$ near $1.$ Since both exponents $x-1,y-1$ are greater than $-1,$ the singulaties (if there are any) at $0,1$ are integrable.